# can not connect client to the sever sockt.io

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io

why do I get this error and can't connect the client to the server, I searched and tried so many trials but it does not work!?

`Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:9000/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=NNM-Vip' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

server:

```
const app = express();
const socket = require("socket.io");
const http = require("http");
const cors = require("cors");
app.use(cors());
const port = process.env.PORT || 9000;
const server = http.createServer(app);

const io = socket(server);

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  console.log("connected successfully....");
  console.log(socket);
});

server.listen(port, () => {
  console.log("listening to port " + port);
});
const io = new socket(server, { cors: { origin: '*' } });
```

client:

```
import io from "socket.io-client";

export default function Chat() {
  const User = useContext(UserContext);
  const EndPoint = "http://localhost:9000/";

  useEffect(() => {
    const socket = io(EndPoint);
    console.log(socket);
    socket.emit("connection", User);
  });
```

Comment: which version of socket.io you are using ??

Comment: Last version 3.0.2